# libobjc.A.dylib crashed? How can I debug?

Tags: objective-c, crash, libobjc

```
Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x30d4af80 objc_msgSend + 32
1   CoreUI                              0x28dce2b9 -[CUIMutableStructuredThemeStore imagesWithName:] + 117
2   UIKit                               0x26d26f49 -[UIImageAsset unregisterImageWithTraitCollection:] + 133
3   UIKit                               0x26d27743 -[_UIPathLazyImageAsset _clearResolvedImageResources] + 171
4   UIKit                               0x26c7997d -[_UIAssetManager _clearCachedResources:] + 225
5   CoreFoundation                      0x2316cf15 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 13
6   CoreFoundation                      0x230c7e4d _CFXNotificationPost + 1801
7   Foundation                          0x23dfce61 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 77
8   Foundation                          0x23e019df -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 31
9   UIKit                               0x268c0143 -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] + 139
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3129f40f _dispatch_client_callout + 23
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x312b4709 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 621
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x312adf3d _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 213
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x312aa035 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 329
14  CoreFoundation                      0x2317a631 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
15  CoreFoundation                      0x23178d51 __CFRunLoopRun + 1513
16  CoreFoundation                      0x230c5b31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
17  CoreFoundation                      0x230c5943 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
18  GraphicsServices                    0x2a47a051 GSEventRunModal + 137
19  UIKit                               0x266b7f21 UIApplicationMain + 1441
20  BaiduHD                             0x0094e2a9 main (main.m:17)
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x312daaaf start + 3
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3138c2c8 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x312aeb7b _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 39
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3138c580 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   BaiduHD                             0x0068c7b5 __23-[CrabANRMonitor start]_block_invoke (CrabANRMonitor.m:84)
2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3129f423 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x312ab2db _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 851
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x312ac1fb _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 107
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ce25 _pthread_wqthread + 669
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb78 start_wqthread + 8
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3138c518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2317a59b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 147
2   CoreFoundation                      0x23178b61 __CFRunLoopRun + 1017
3   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5b31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
4   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5943 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   WebCore                             0x2e729819 RunWebThread() + 417
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ee67 _pthread_body + 139
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141eddb _pthread_start + 119
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb84 thread_start + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3138c518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2317a59b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 147
2   CoreFoundation                      0x23178b61 __CFRunLoopRun + 1017
3   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5b31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
4   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5943 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   Foundation                          0x23e028f1 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 265
6   Foundation                          0x23e50d65 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 81
7   BaiduHD                             0x00c1d8bf +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:169)
8   Foundation                          0x23ec793b __NSThread__main__ + 1119
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ee67 _pthread_body + 139
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141eddb _pthread_start + 119
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb84 thread_start + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3138c518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2317a59b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 147
2   CoreFoundation                      0x23178b61 __CFRunLoopRun + 1017
3   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5b31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
4   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5943 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   CFNetwork                           0x22c7a78f +NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 487
6   Foundation                          0x23ec793b __NSThread__main__ + 1119
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ee67 _pthread_body + 139
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141eddb _pthread_start + 119
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb84 thread_start + 8
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x313a008c select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ee67 _pthread_body + 139
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141eddb _pthread_start + 119
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb84 thread_start + 8
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x313a09cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb78 start_wqthread + 8
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3138c518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2317a59b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 147
2   CoreFoundation                      0x23178b61 __CFRunLoopRun + 1017
3   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5b31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
4   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5943 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   BaiduHD                             0x00c40917 +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:4798)
6   Foundation                          0x23ec793b __NSThread__main__ + 1119
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ee67 _pthread_body + 139
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141eddb _pthread_start + 119
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb84 thread_start + 8
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x313a09cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb78 start_wqthread + 8
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3138c518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2317a59b _CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 147
2   CoreFoundation                      0x23178b61 __CFRunLoopRun + 1017
3   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5b31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
4   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5943 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x21de93ed GenericRunLoopThread::Entry() + 133
6   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x21ddb8e7 CAPThread::Entry() + 195
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ee67 _pthread_body + 139
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141eddb _pthread_start + 119
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb84 thread_start + 8
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3138c518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2317a59b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 147
2   CoreFoundation                      0x23178b61 __CFRunLoopRun + 1017
3   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5b31 RunLoopRunSpecific + 477
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2310f4fb CFRunLoopRun + 99
5   CoreMotion                          0x239ccd23 CLSF_thorntonUpdate_6x6 + 47379
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ee67 _pthread_body + 139
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141eddb _pthread_start + 119
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb84 thread_start + 8
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x313a09cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb78 start_wqthread + 8
Thread 13:
   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3138c518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2317a59b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 147
2   CoreFoundation                      0x23178b61 __CFRunLoopRun + 1017
3   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5b31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
4   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5943 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   Foundation                          0x23e028f1 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 265
6   Foundation                          0x23e50d65 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 81
7   BaiduHD                             0x0067a365 +[CrabURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (CrabURLConnectionOperation.m:152)
8   Foundation                          0x23ec793b __NSThread__main__ + 1119
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ee67 _pthread_body + 139
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141eddb _pthread_start + 119
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb84 thread_start + 8
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3139fb38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141f2b1 pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   libc++.1.dylib                      0x30508fa9 std::__1::condition_variable::wait() + 37
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x24388f3b JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 215
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x243853ef WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint() + 15
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ee67 _pthread_body + 139
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141eddb _pthread_start + 119
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb84 thread_start + 8
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3139fb38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141f2b1 pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   libc++.1.dylib                      0x30508fa9 std::__1::condition_variable::wait() + 37
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x2454db05 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 105
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x2454db69 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 53
5   JavaScriptCore                      0x243853ef WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint() + 15
   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ee67 _pthread_body + 139
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141eddb _pthread_start + 119
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb84 thread_start + 8

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x313a09cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb78 start_wqthread + 8
Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x313a09cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb78 start_wqthread + 8
Thread 18 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x30d4af66 objc_msgSend + 6
1   libcache.dylib                      0x312380a5 _value_entry_remove + 141
2   libcache.dylib                      0x31236beb _entry_evict + 131
3   libcache.dylib                      0x31237d99 _evict_last + 145
4   libcache.dylib                      0x31237f2d _cache_enforce_limits + 101
5  libcache.dylib                      0x31237eb1 ___cache_handle_memory_pressure_event_block_invoke + 49
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3129f423 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x312ab2db _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 851
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x312ac1fb _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 107
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ce25 _pthread_wqthread + 669
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb78 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x313a09cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb78 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3139fb38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141f2f1 pthread_cond_timedwait + 45
2   libc++.1.dylib                      0x30509079 s::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait() + 185
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x244ad791 std::__1::condition_variable::wait_for >() + 201
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x24388ebb JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 87
5   JavaScriptCore                      0x243853ef WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint() + 15
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ee67 _pthread_body + 139
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141eddb _pthread_start + 119
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb84 thread_start + 8

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3139fb38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141f2b1 pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   libc++.1.dylib                      0x30508fa9 std::__1::condition_variable::wait() + 37
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x2454db05 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 105
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x2454db69 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 53
5   JavaScriptCore                      0x243853ef WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint() + 15
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ee67 _pthread_body + 139
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141eddb _pthread_start + 119
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb84 thread_start + 8
Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3138c518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2317a59b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 147
2   CoreFoundation                      0x23178b61 __CFRunLoopRun + 1017
3   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5b31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
   CoreFoundation                      0x230c5943 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   WebCore                             0x2e752b55 WebCore::runLoaderThread() + 293
6   JavaScriptCore                      0x243853ef WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint() + 15
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141ee67 _pthread_body + 139
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141eddb _pthread_start + 119
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3141cb84 thread_start + 8
Thread 18 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    pc: 0x30d4af66     r7: 0x05039f10     sp: 0x05039efc     r0: 0x31773a5d 
    r1: 0x233d6fea     r2: 0x177246d0     r3: 0x18845e90     r4: 0x18845e90 
    r5: 0x177246d0     r6: 0x31773a5d     r8: 0x00000000     r9: 0xa123a48f 
   r10: 0x316a6fa4    r11: 0x1773a518     ip: 0x316837f0     lr: 0x231f4c29 
  cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Thread 18 crashed.

`UIWebView` maybe load this url https://www.baidu.com/s?bundleid=com.baidu.BaiduHD&ie=utf-8&wd=%E5%9B%BD%E4%BA%A7psp4000&dsp=ipad&tn=SE_baiduipadhd2_22k1x757&rn=10&rsv_baiduhdpage=4&openudid=8ae020abea3190f77b90d055201d5886b5c03a29&hsug_mtype=0

This is the collapse of the log information. I did not replicate the collapse. Can you give me some advice about how to debug?

Comment: Maybe it will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/39560929/3718570