# EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) on Production Version Only

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My iOS app works fine in testing but crashes on startup with the release version downloaded from the App Store. I've tried retesting with the release build configuration in Xcode and it doesn't crash, just the store version. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with in-app purchase products loading, but can't narrow it down due to not being able to replicate it in a test environment and am having trouble reading the log. The device log is showing this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  5

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
1.456537     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b13755 TCP Conn 0x16696ed0 SSL Handshake DONE
1.507619     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b13755 TCP Conn 0x16697670 SSL Handshake DONE
1.618210     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b1368f TCP Conn 0x16696ed0 starting SSL negotiation
1.619545     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b1368f TCP Conn 0x16697670 starting SSL negotiation
1.619545     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b9387d TCP Conn 0x16696ed0 complete. fd: 12, err: 0
1.620001     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b9387d TCP Conn 0x16697670 complete. fd: 10, err: 0
1.621124     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b94977 TCP Conn 0x16696ed0 event 1. err: 0
1.622355     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b94977 TCP Conn 0x16697670 event 1. err: 0
1.699555     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b949f5 TCP Conn 0x16697670 started
1.699555     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b949f5 TCP Conn 0x16696ed0 started
1.757512     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b13755 TCP Conn 0x16684640 SSL Handshake DONE
2.136019     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b1368f TCP Conn 0x16684640 starting SSL negotiation
2.136958     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b9387d TCP Conn 0x16684640 complete. fd: 5, err: 0
2.139006     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b94977 TCP Conn 0x16684640 event 1. err: 0
2.400334     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025b949f5 TCP Conn 0x16684640 started
2.412851     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025bda15f Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
2.412851     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025bda13b Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
2.412851     CFNetwork                  0x0000000025c1c7bf Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2528a8d0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2528a6d4 mach_msg + 40
2   CoreFoundation                  0x255d5ac4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136
3   CoreFoundation                  0x255d3e4c __CFRunLoopRun + 1036
4   CoreFoundation                  0x25523228 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x25523014 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
6   GraphicsServices                0x26b13ac8 GSEventRunModal + 160
7   UIKit                           0x29bf7188 UIApplicationMain + 144
8   LeaseLocator_2016               0x000bfe88 0x53000 + 446088
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x251cb872 start + 2

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x252a02f8 kevent_qos + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x25195d60 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 256
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x25195abe _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 38

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2529f864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25345b34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25345718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2529f864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25345b34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25345718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2529f864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25345b34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25345718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x1666ba80 :: NSOperation 0x165dafe0 (QOS: LEGACY)
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   LeaseLocator_2016               0x00079894 0x53000 + 157844
1   LeaseLocator_2016               0x00073d90 0x53000 + 134544
2   LeaseLocator_2016               0x000788d0 0x53000 + 153808
3   CFNetwork                       0x25b1b280 __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 16
4   CFNetwork                       0x25b2aa6a __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 278
5   Foundation                      0x25e25678 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 8
6   Foundation                      0x25d865f2 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 146
7   Foundation                      0x25d78bc8 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 768
8   Foundation                      0x25e27930 __NSOQSchedule_f + 192
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x2518e422 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 1758
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x2518da60 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 284
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x2519015c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x2518ffcc _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 96
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25345b28 _pthread_wqthread + 1024
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25345718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2529f864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25345b34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25345718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25345710 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2528a8d0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2528a6d4 mach_msg + 40
2   CoreFoundation                  0x255d5ac4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136
3   CoreFoundation                  0x255d3e4c __CFRunLoopRun + 1036
4   CoreFoundation                  0x25523228 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x25523014 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
6   CFNetwork                       0x25b749f6 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 486
7   Foundation                      0x25e3d4a4 __NSThread__start__ + 1148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2534785a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x253477ce _pthread_start + 110
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25345724 thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2529eeec __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x255daf12 __CFSocketManager + 566
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2534785a _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x253477ce _pthread_start + 110
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x25345724 thread_start + 8

Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x402190b0      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x165d5790    r5: 0x00421c86      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x40218b48
    r8: 0x16696b50    r9: 0x16696b54     r10: 0x00000001     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x000d3274    sp: 0x40218a80      lr: 0x00078c08      pc: 0x00079894
  cpsr: 0x60000010
```

Is there some way I can either test the production build from the store or does this log provide enough information to pinpoint where my error is?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you call in the app Contacts, Calendar, Reminders, Photos, Bluetooth Sharing, Microphone, Camera, Location, Health, HomeKit, Media Library, Motion, CallKit, Speech Recognition, SiriKit, TV Provider, etc.

Since iOS 10 your app will crash if you try to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.

To avoid the crash you need to add the key to ‘Info.plist’, for example:

```
Privacy - Camera Usage Description
Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
```

In my case I added key for camera usage but not for microphone and had the same problem.

Comment: I do have that key include in my plist as I use location, but if that wasn't the case wouldn't the app also crash during testing?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem a few weeks ago, and it was incredibly frustrating to not be able to test it. What I did, while not a perfect solution, did allow me to test the issue.

Go into your project's Build Settings, and down to Signing. All of the fields under Code Signing Identity should say "iOS Developer". Change them all to iOS Distribution. Build and run your app, and it should hopefully crash. Now, you'll be able to figure out what's going on through Xcode.

Also, once you fix the problem, make sure to return those code signing identites back to normal.

Comment: No Luck, Set all code signing to Distribution and it all worked fine.